# php ms sql server stored procedure return json string max 2034

Tags: php, sql-server

PHP reads just 2034 characters from the returned JSON string value from stored procedure "sp_test". Why just 2034 characters and not more?

Using PHP Version 5.6.31 with SQL Express 2017

```
$query = "EXEC sp_test";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($GLOBALS['connIntern'], $query);
if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
    if (($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: " . $error['SQLSTATE'] . "<br />";
            echo "code: " . $error['code'] . "<br />";
            echo "message: " . $error['message'] . "<br />";
        }
    }
    die;
}
$array = [];
if (!empty($result)) {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($array, $row[0]);
    }
}
return $array;
```

Stored Procedure "sp_test":

```
SELECT [Tracking].[orderNumber],[Tracking].[tcpState], [Stations].[startdate],[Stations].[enddate],[Stations].[tcpState],[Stations].[name]
FROM [Tracking]
LEFT JOIN [Stations] ON [Tracking].[orderNumber] = [Stations][orderNumber]
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Formatted result:

```
[
    {
        "orderNumber": 123455,
        "tcpState": 3,
        "Stations": [
            {
                "startdate": "2011-05-06",
                "enddate": "2012-09-15",
                "tcpState": 3,
                "name": "Roger"
            },
            {
                "startdate": "2011-02-06",
                "enddate": "2012-05-15",
                "tcpState": 4,
                "name": "Hans"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "orderNumber": 1566,
        "tcpState": 3,
        "Stations": [
            {
                "startdate": "2011-06-06",
                "enddate": "2012-08-15",
                "tcpState": "6",
                "name": "Mike"
            },
            {
                "startdate": "2011-03-06",
                "enddate": "2012-03-15",
                "tcpState": "6",
                "name": "Tom"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You have the beginnings of a good question here, but there's far too little detail (sample code, results, etc) to allow anyone to answer it with any degree of certainty.

Comment: That result doesn't look like it's being cut off.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. You have two orders, each with two stations. The JSON isn't being truncated. SQL Server can return the equivalent of an NVARCHAR(max) so that shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found the issue

```
if (!empty($result)) {
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($array, $row[0]);
}
```

I thought i get the whole string in one row but i have to merge it.Like this:

```
if (!empty($result)) {
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($array, $row);
        }
    }

    if(count($array) > 0){
        foreach ($array as $json){
            $jsonPiece = $json[0];
            $jsonString .= $jsonPiece;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For PDO-driver use this :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM); // array

$jsonString=""; // final JSON-string

foreach ($result as $row) {
    $jsonString .=$row[0];
}
```